# Reliable antenna matching design of quadrifillar helix

Tags: antenna, matching, balun

I have simulated this antenna :

[image]

I found its impedance, I know I have 50 ohm transmission. I decided to match these by discrete part in feed point, The match circuit is

[image]

I want to ask from those who are experienced that is this way of design acceptable and reliable? If not what is the correct way. Note that I have no analyzer. I just have oscilloscope and multi-meter. Also I don't know how I can make current balun?

Comment: Please begin sentences with capital letter. Word is your friend.

Comment: At 1580 MHz you might look into Marchand type baluns or a bazooka type balun. You're probably not going to do very well with a lumped element balun.

Comment: Ok! Ty! But what about matching network?? If I not use lumped match, How I can match? And is voltage baun not important? Can u explain how to make Marchand type balun (Or give some refrence).